# What's the point of allowEditing in UIImagePicker?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am not sure I understand `allowEditing` functionality in `UIImagePicker`. I've read official Apple documentation, which states it allows edit images, but all I get is square. Even worse, as in some case user can not select bottom of the image. Does `allowEditing` can provide more functionality besides that square, for example rotate image, allow select bottom of the image?

Comment: Do you give "UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage" or "UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage" parameter to the image picker?

Comment: When I want chosen image to be saved or shown on screen? Then I chose `Edited`